# How do I configure Spring Integration for TCP to send data to a Socket Server without facing a timeout error?

Tags: sockets, tcp, spring-integration

1. Start Socket Server
2. Running Spring Integration TCP Outbound Gateway.
3. Expected is to Outboung Gateway able to send data to Socket Server and Socket server should be receiving it.

But it is not happenning.
Can you take a look.

```
public TcpOutboundGateway buildTcpGateway() {
        return buildGatewayInternal(getEndpoint());
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetClientConnectionFactory initTcpNetClientConnectionFactory() {
        final TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        connectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);
        connectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory initThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory() {
        return new ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory(initTcpNetClientConnectionFactory());
    }

    public TcpOutboundGateway buildGatewayInternal(String endpoint) {
        final TcpOutboundGateway gateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        setHostAndPort();
        gateway.setConnectionFactory(initThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory());
        gateway.setRequiresReply(false);
        gateway.setRequestTimeout(dmvConfig.getConnectTimeout());
        gateway.setRemoteTimeout(dmvConfig.getTimeout());
        final QueueChannel outputChannel = new QueueChannel();
        final DirectChannel directChannel = new DirectChannel();
        gateway.setOutputChannel(outputChannel);
        gateway.setReplyChannel(directChannel);
        gateway.start();
        gateway.setUnsolicitedMessageChannelName("unsolicited");
        final Message<String> message = new GenericMessage<String>("foo\r\n");
        gateway.handleMessage(message);

        return gateway;
    }
```

`

- Stack Trace

[ERROR] 2023-05-26 18:33:56.751 [main] TcpOutboundGateway - [error] - Tcp Gateway exception
org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:293) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.5.15.jar:5.5.15]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:234) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.5.15.jar:5.5.15]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar:5.5.15]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar:5.5.15]
at buildGatewayInternal(DmvGateway.java:114) ~[classes/:?]
at buildTcpGateway(DmvGateway.java:84) ~[classes/:?]
at DmvGatewayTest.testNetClient(DmvGatewayTest.java:70) ~[test-classes/:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]``

Comment: We need to see a code of your server. The error you got is talking about a reply which has to be sent back from the server. According to you description it does not look like you aware of the gateway nature. Please, be sure that you use a delimiter for message expected by your server: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-codecs

Comment: Thankyou for reply. There are following observations
1. Default Serializer and Deserializer are ByteArrayCrlfSerializer. So 
2. Message must be delimited by Carriage Return + Line Feed,
3. Only Spring Integration Socket Server (TCP Inbound Gateway)(using Default serializer) able to decode message sent from Spring Integration Socket Client (TCP OutboundGateway)
4. Using Any other socket server is unable to read data and waiting for reply - resulting in Timeout.
5. Was able to solve this situation as described in #3

Comment: OK. Sounds like too much missed info in the question, but I'm glad you have figured it  out. Feel free to add an answer for you own question. I believe those "Any other socket server" are just not able to demarcate messages properly: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-codecs